# Is it possible to edit config files for Linux server using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a Powershell script that can edit config files for linux servers after I SSH into it.

The purpose of this script is to automate configuration of linux servers for a security tool I use at work. Instead of the manual process [SSH linux server in cmd, opening and editing config files in vim] I want to create a script to do this for me.

I have read a lot of documentation for bash scripts, but I didn’t find much information about integrating Powershell with Linux servers.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Could you please provide a more specific description of your problem and what code you have tried already to solve it.

Comment: @Strom 

I want to create a script that can add text to a config file in Linux server after I SSH into it through Powershell.

I wanted to know if this is possible using Powershell instead of logging in through cmd and using vim for it.


I can update the question with the code I wrote to SSH into server and send some commands but this is more of a prerequisite question than a coding question

Comment: I have updated my question. I am not looking for coding help here. I am new to Powershell and want to know if it is possible to do something like this.

Comment: Asking "integrating Powershell with Linux servers" is like asking how to integrate CMD with Powershell?? On Linux you can use bash and the associated text processing commands: cat, echo, cut, grep, awk, head, tail, sed (they are extremely powerful) to edit the file and add the required line(s). All of these commands can be scripted and sent from powershell through SSH to bash for interpretation. If you feel more comfortable with text processing in powershell(?), It is possible to read a cat of the file(or scp per @dan1st) and process it and save it.

Comment: @Gaurav perhaps have a look at **Powershell core**. Its more or less Powershell for windows linux and mac. Perhaps this will help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use SCP.

With SCP, you can transfer files via SSH. So, you can download a file, edit it locally and then upload it.

To download a file use:

```
scp <IP>:<remote file> <local file>
```

To upload a file use:

```
scp <local file> <IP>:<remote file>
```

You can also use `<Username>[:<Password>]@<IP>` or other authentication methods that work with SSH like Public Key Authentication.

Comment: SCP can not "Add text to a config file". Assuming permissions you can replace a file, but you cannot edit one.